# How Do I update Javascript To Return 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, null

How do I change Javascript to update to one?

Comment: `leave the 'quantity: null' out of the array entirely` - you mean out of the Object?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Have you tried anything so far? One approach would be forEaching or mapping over the array, checking for a null key.

Comment: is your question regarding how to change the code you've posted in the question? because `I need to feed the array into the 'this.list'` looks confusing .. this.list is an empty array

Comment: I am familiar with the if statement and I've tried a few different things with it but to no avail. I've tried .forEach too but am missing something. I know it's probably easy and staring me right in the face but I can't figure out what it is. Javascript is new to me. In the real life problem there are more items in the array as well as prices. I'm trying to feed them into the this.list array so that I can calculate costs. If leaving 'quantity: null' out of the array entirely, and have something in the class that see there is nothing there and replaces it with one, that's an option too.

Comment: I've added a little more to the example so maybe you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As it stands, for the second item in the array, I'm getting back Nan. I need to be able to get a price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a few of options here. First you could create a prototype for your object and default the value in the constructor. I.e.

```
function Foo(name, quantity) {
   this.name = name;
   this.quantity = !quantity && quantity !== 0 ? 1 : quantity;
}
```

Then, when you instantiate your array you can use the `new Foo(name, quantity);` constructor to create your object, if quantity is `null` or `undefined`, the default value 1 will be used.

```
var arr= [new Foo('a', 1), new Foo('b')];
```

See the attached snipped for examples on the behavior of the constructor for `falsy values`.

Another option would be to use a `forEach` to iterate throught the array and reasign the value of `quantity` if its `null`, but this feels dirty.

i.e.

```
arr.forEach( x => { x.quantity = !x.quantity && x.quantity !== 0 ? 1 : x.quantity })
```

```js
function Foo(name, quantity) {
  this.name = name;
  this.quantity = !quantity && quantity !== 0 ? 1 : quantity;
}

var foo = new Foo('stuff', null);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, '\t'));

foo = new Foo('stuff', undefined);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, '\t'));

foo = new Foo('stuff', 0);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, '\t'));

foo = new Foo('stuff', -1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, null, '\t'));


var arr= [new Foo('a', 1), new Foo('b')];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t'));
```

**Update**

Ok based on your updated code, you can simply create a class for the Item, and  just set the value from the constructor. Then you can define a class for the list so you can wrap the functionality for calculating the total, and for concatenating an array of items. Check the snippet bellow for a working example.

```js
class Item {
   constructor(name, price, quantity){
      this.name = name;
      this.price = price;
      this.quantity = !quantity && quantity !== 0 ? 1 : quantity;
   }
}

class SomeList {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }

    addItems(list) {
        list.forEach(x => {
            this.items.push(x);
        });
    }

    get total() {
        var t = 0;
        this.items.forEach(i => { t += (i.price * i.quantity); });
        return t;
    }
}

// define the array of items, using the constructor of the item class
var arr = [ new Item('a', 100, 1), new Item('b', 50) ];

// Create the list and add the items
var list = new SomeList();
list.addItems(arr);

// get the total
var total = list.total;

console.log('Total '+ list.total);
```

Comment: Would the function go inside the class?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by 'could create a prototype for your object and default the value in the constructor'.

Comment: Are you using es6 classes? If you are the you should simply use a class instead of an object prototype. If not you need to declare the prototype in your script

Comment: The function Foo is the object prototype, could be considered the equivalent of a class definition for plain JavaScript.

Comment: I believe it es6. You have to forgive me, cause I'm really new to this so a lot of the jargon is still shaky to me. Are you saying that 'this.quantity = !quantity && quantity !== 0 ? 1 : quantity;' could be a definition in the constructor? So this.quantity = your code? When I try that I still get a 'Nan' back.

Comment: No worries! Yes, you should add the logic to default the quantity inside the constructor. You should be able to just copy the line 'this.quantity = ...' inside the constructor.

Comment: I updated the answer with a new snippet based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and effective solution would be to use `.map()` to modify the items with `null` quantities before you process the array further or pass it to the list:

```
array.map(i => ((i.quantity = i.quantity || 1), i))
```

Demo code in the snippet below:

```js
let array = [{name: 'a', price: 1, quantity: 1}, {name: 'b', price: 1, quantity: null}];

let updatedArray = array.map(i => ((i.quantity = i.quantity || 1), i));

console.log(updatedArray);
```

Comment: That just seems to filter out the item altogether rather than return 1 in place of null.

Comment: @JerryTiller, misunderstood the question, updated answer.